# Jquery Ajax Autocomplete with codeigniter 'term' issues

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

My ajax **autocomplete does return the countries from the server but** it does always show **all** countries **whatever I type**. There is something wrong with sending the request.term to controller to Model but I can't figure out what it is. Thanks very much for any hint!

html:

```
<input type='text' name='location_search' id='location_search' placeholder='Type Location' >
```

js:

```
$(function(){
    var $sfield = $('#location_search').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response){
            var url = "<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/control_areas'); ?>";
              $.post(url, {data:request.term}, function(data){
                response($.map(data, function(countries) {
                    return {
                        value: countries.name_en
                    };
                }));
              }, "json");  
        },
        minLength: 2,
        autofocus: true
    });
});
```

controller:

```
function control_areas(){
    $this->load->model('autocomplete_model');
    $term = $this->input->get('term', TRUE);
    $countries = $this->autocomplete_model->get_areas($term);
    echo json_encode($countries);
}
```

model:

```
function get_areas($term){
    $this->db->where('name_en', $term);
    $query = $this->db->get('countries');
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you get an expected value for `$term = $this->input->get('term', TRUE);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your model, it should be like this:

```
function get_areas($term){
    $this->db->like('name_en', $term, 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get('countries');
    return $query->result(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple little thing:

```
$this->db->like
```

instead of

```
$this->db->where
```